# How to inject parameters to Kotlin extension functions using Dagger Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, extension-methods, dagger-hilt

I have an extension function which formats Int to currency string

```kotlin
fun Int.asCurrency(formatter: NumberFormat): String {
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    return formatter.format(this)
}
```

Here I pass NumberFormat instance to the function, since I don't want to create new instance everytime inside the function when using this function in a recyclerview.

I can create a Singleton object class and create NumberFormat there and use it everywhere.

```kotlin
object Formatter {
    val currencyFormatter: NumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault())
}

fun Int.asCurrency(): String {
    Formatter.currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    return Formatter.currencyFormatter.format(this)
}
```

But I was learning Dependency Injection, so I wanted to Inject NumberFormat instance into the function.

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object FormatterModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCurrencyFormatter(): NumberFormat {
        return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault())
    }
}

@Inject
fun Int.asCurrency(formatter: NumberFormat): String {
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    return formatter.format(this)
}
```

The above didn't work. When I call the function it asks for the parameter. Then i tried field injection

```kotlin
@Inject
fun Int.asCurrency(): String {
    lateinit var formatter: NumberFormat
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    return formatter.format(this)
}
```

But this gives the compilation error `error: Dagger does not support injection into static methods`.

Can anyone please tell me how I can inject function parameters into Kotlin extension functions? Or can I at least inject parameters into normal Kotlin functions?

Comment: Haven't tried as per your scenario but have you tried this ? https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani Doc says `you must use the ApplicationContext to retrieve the entry point because the entry point is installed in SingletonComponent`. I don't have access to ApplicationContext in extension function.